# How to get document generation progress in XDocReport?

Tags: java, xdocreport

In our project, report generation can take a very long time. Is there a way to obtain number of generated pages while the document is processed?

Simple progress bar is not enough, we need to show users that something is really happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDocReport doesn't provide a **kind of progress monitor**. I think this idea could be interesting, please [create an issue](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/list) for that.

It should be interesting too to know where report generation can take a very long time. The report process is :

1. **generate docx (or odt) from a docx (or odt) template**. Is this step takes time? If it takes time, I think you don't use **XDocReport cache** (retrieve the report from the registry instead of loading very time the docx/odt template)
2. **convert the generated docx to PDF**. I think this step can takes time. For that, I'm afraid that you cannot improve performance.

The progress monitor could track step 1 and 2:

- for step 1 you cannot know the page because docx doesn't contain information about page.
- for step 2 I think we could track PDF page if you use our POI/iText converter that we will able to modify to support progress monitor.

Comment: It is simply a matter of very large amount of data. I am yet to test it with full set of data, but it could take a very long time, although it is quicker than Jasper we have used previously.

Comment: if you don't convert your docx -> pdf, is it slow?

Comment: I still haven't tried conversion, b/c I'll first have to figure out table of contents updating. We have toc inside a template, which should be updated, after the data is applied. I thought XDocReport had these functionality, but it doesn't, and I'll have to build it from scratch.