# Javafx, xdocreport and Thread - creating report

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, xdocreport

I want to implement progress bar in JavaFx, that will indicate state of report creating using xdocreport (docx or pdf file). Any sugestions how can I achive that. Some example ? How can I use Thread for that ?

I have tried like this but something is not working.

```
 /**
 * Called when the user clicks the assign button. Generates Report about Employee
 *  
 */
@FXML
private void generateEmployeeReport() {


    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() {


             try {
                 // 1) Load Docx file by filling Velocity template engine and cache
                 // it to the registry
                 InputStream in = RootController.class
                                 .getResourceAsStream("ReportEmployeeTemplate.docx");
                 IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(
                                 in, TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

                 // 2) Create context Java model
                 IContext context = report.createContext();
                 ReportEmployee project = new ReportEmployee("Majmun");
                 context.put("ReportEmployee", project);

                 // 3) Generate report by merging Java model with the Docx
                 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                                 "bzzer.pdf"));


                 // report.process(context, out);
                 Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF).via(
                                 ConverterTypeVia.XWPF);
                 report.convert(context, options, out);


         } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (XDocReportException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }  



            return null;
        }
    };



    progresBarOne.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();

}
```

File is created but progress bar keeps showing some work (Keep "indicating" progress)

Comment: You aren't updating the progress. Use [`updateProgress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress%28long,%20long%29) inside your call to update the progress

Comment: What to use for updateProgress() method arguments ?

Comment: Its all there in the doc, you need to go through it. There are two arguments `workDone` and `totalWork`. So if totalWork is 10, you can pass parameters as (1, 10), (2, 10) and so on

Comment: Thank you very much. But in my case what is the indicator of totalWork and workDone. I am "creating" a pdf file. Maybe size of file ?

Comment: Nope, in your case its complicated, because generally the work is divided in `workDone`. For example, if we writing a file using buffer, for each iteration we can update the progress, until we have written the whole file. Here you do not have any such iterations. You will have to decide it how do you want to update the progress.

Comment: For iteration topic about XDocReport, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399223/how-to-get-document-generation-progress-in-xdocreport